# $.each() function of Jquery is not answering me

Tags: jquery, each

I have `<div>` elements which has more `<div>` in it and others which has no `<div>` in it. I want name of the divs one by one .but if a div has another div in it I don't want the name of the `.maindiv` but I want the name of `.seconddivs` which is inside of the `.maindiv`.

I draw a scheme for my qustion:
[image]

I will use jquery for this mission so here my code:

```
$.each($("body").find(".maindiv"), function(e) {
        if($(this).find(".seconddivs") == false){
            $(".suggest_for_column").append("<option>"+$(this).children(".nameofthediv").text()+"</option>"); // in this line of code i will append the .nameofthediv (name of my div) to inside a <select> element
        }else{
            $(".suggest_for_column").append("<option>"+$(this).find(".seconddivs").children(".nameofthediv").text()+"</option>");
        }
})
```

I don't know where this code is wrong, but it is not working at all( nothing happens )

Comment: Normally you use the `.each()` method to iterate over jQuery collections. `$.each()` is used for iterating over arrays and objects.

Comment: You can get the name like this  `$.each($(".maindiv"), function(e) { var name = $(this).has(".seconddivs") ? $('.seconddivs',this).attr('name') :  $(this).attr('name'); //remaining code ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` doesn't return true or false, it returns a jQuery object containing any matching elements.

So you can check its `length`:

```
$.each($("body").find(".maindiv"), function(e) {
        var secondDivs = $(this).find(".seconddivs");
        if(secondDivs.length){
            // It has them, use them
        }else{
            // It doesn't have them
        }
});
```

I removed the code in the clauses because it has syntax errors. You're using `.` incorrectly, I suspect you meant to use `+` (for string concatenation).

Side note: The usual way to write `$.each($("body").find(".maindiv"), function{})` is `$(".maindiv").each(function{})`.

Comment: i did my work with your codes and thanks for that but in codes `if(secondDivs.length){// It has them, use them}` sections chooses divs which has not `.seconddivs` in it. and `else{}` chooses divs which has `.seconddivs` in it. i didn't understand why

Comment: @user3301042: It's the other way around. `if (secondDivs.length)` checks to see if `length` is "falsey" (in this case, checks that it is not zero). So the block that follows is for doing something with `secondDivs`, since it's not empty. The `else` block is for when the div *doesn't* have any `secondDivs`.